# Antivirus for Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If a malicious user tamper with the file placed in AppServices and incorporate the virus, is there a way to know that? For example, installing antivirus software on a virtual machine and keep it in the same way.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387004/antimalware-for-azure-app-services

I am looking at this URL for reference and I understand that using Tinfoil Security meets the requirements. However, Tinfoil Security can not be used because the license I use is Japanese CSP.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/TrustCenter/Security/ThreatManagement

I also saw this URL, but my English skill is not adequate, so my understanding may be less than enough. Therefore, I need some details. Was "Azure cloud service" written as "Azure cloud service and virtual machine's Microsoft antimalware" include AppService? I thought that only the cloud service was covered. For example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/

I am checking whether the file size and timestamp has been changed in the AppServices web job, but please let me know if there are things that can be covered with the functions provided as a service of Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service uses the Anti-malware solution used by **Azure Cloud Services** and **Virtual Machines**. 
This is mentioned here: [App Service Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-security-readme)

This further points to the following article: [Microsoft Antimalware for Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-antimalware)

For extended scenarios Tinfoil was provided as an additional option. If that is not available to you, then using **Azure Cloud Services** (**Web Roles**) is more inline with your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That means I should understand that Anti-malware solution is running on Azure App Service?

Therefore, Azure App Service has protection from malware. And I understood that Tinfoil Security should be used to further secure Azure App Service

Comment: Understood. Thank you.