# Anti-malware on Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, antivirus

I created this test program that writes the EICAR test virus to a file. On my computer the virus is found by F-Secure after a few iterations. On Azure App Service (on Windows), it runs all the 100 iterations.

```
var filepath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "/test.com";

await File.WriteAllTextAsync(filepath, @"X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*");

int iterations = 0;
while (File.Exists(filepath) && iterations < 100)
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    iterations++;

    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Iterations: {iterations}\n\r");
}
```

Does that mean that no anti-malware, not even Windows Defender, is enabled on the VMs that Azure App Service uses?

Comment: `Does that mean that no anti-malware` I wouldn't draw conclusions **that** quickly, but it sure is a good indication that you **may** be on to something. For now I'd conclude: more testing needed. However, the real question is: what if there is/isn't? Does it matter to you? How? Why? Why not?

Comment: We have an application where users can submit a form with attachments. I would like to scan these attachments before saving them. The traditional way is to save them to disk, wait some seconds and see if the file is still there or if anti-malware has removed it.

Comment: `The traditional way is to […] has removed it` Traditional? I don't think there's a traditional way, and if there is, I disagree that this (upload, wait, see if it vanished) is the way to go. I would run an explicit check instead of relying on a 'magic number of seconds' (what if the antivirus is busy and takes a bit longer?). Also: now you're assuming Azure is providing you with 'free antivirus capabilities'; I'm quite sure it doesn't mention any of that in your 'agreement' because then you'll hold them liable if something slips through. You'll have to implement an (explicit) check yourself.

Comment: You can upvote this:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17919064-antimalware-feature-on-web-apps-app-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antimalware for Azure App Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387004/antimalware-for-azure-app-services)